# Determining which voter is providing authorisation

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony5

I have a `@Security("is_granted('ROLE_NAME', parameter)")` annotation above a route that's not behaving as I expect, in that authorisation is granted when it shouldn't be and the custom voter I've written never even gets reached - leading me to suspect that some other voter is being asked first and providing authorisation. **How would I go about finding which voter is providing authorisation for a certain `is_granted` call?**

Comment: can you share your security.yml config? What role are you assigning to your logged in user?

Comment: You can use the profiler (security tab) to see the executed voters and their vote